# Showing markup as a literal string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JavaScript function like this which evaluates text added to a TextBox and it half works.

```
    function HTMLDecode(t) {
        if (t) return $('<div />').html(t).text();
    }
```

For instance adding `<b>bold text</b>` to the textBox will save the text to the database as entered, but will retrieve and display it as bold text, although unformatted. Is there a way to retrieve and display `<b>bold text</b>`?

Comment: You can run the string through [`HtmlEncode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-6.0) before saving it to your database. Alternatively, output the value with [`Html.Raw()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2. In either case ***be very careful to secure your code again XSS attacks*** when you allow users to input HTML in to your system which is later displayed within a web page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan HtmlHelper.Raw is a server side method - is there a way of doing it client side in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Sure, use `pre` element instead of `div`. But as I mentioned above, you're leaving yourself open to XSS if you don't sanitise the HTML on the server side.